# Appending json file in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have json file `ticket.json`

```
"{\"Item1\":[{\"Id\":2,\"Title\":\"Support\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":14},{\"Id\":8,\"Title\":\"Helpdesk\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1},{\"Id\":7,\"Title\":\"Hostmaster\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1},{\"Id\":4,\"Title\":\"Salg\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1}],\"Item2\":[{\"Id\":8,\"FullName\":\"person 1\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":5},{\"Id\":3,\"FullName\":\"Person 2\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":4},{\"Id\":11,\"FullName\":\"Person 3\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":3},{\"Id\":14,\"FullName\":\"Person 4\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1},{\"Id\":12,\"FullName\":\"Person 5\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1},{\"Id\":7,\"FullName\":\"Person 7\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1},{\"Id\":4,\"FullName\":\"Person 8\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1}]}"
```

and I am trying to append it to index.html.
So far I have tried below codes and I am able to se json file in console.log.
But i do get an error XML tolkningsfail which I do not understand why.
Could anyone help me out to solve the problem.
Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=UTF-8>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var dashboard = [];
   $.getJSON('ticket.json', function(data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
    var keys = Object.keys(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(keys[i])) {
            $.each(data[keys[i]], function (index, item) {
                var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + item.Id + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.Title + "</td>" +"<td>" + item.TotalUnresolvedItems + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                var tblRow2 = "<tr>" + "<td>" + item.Id + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.FullName + "</td>" +"<td>" + item.TotalUnresolvedItems + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
                $(tblRow2).appendTo("#userdata2 tbody");
            });
        }
    }
     });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
    <table id= "userdata" border="2">
     <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>TotalUnresolvedItems</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

       </tbody>
   </table>

       <table id= "userdata2" border="2">
     <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>FullName</th>
        <th>TotalUnresolvedItems</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elmJSON = "{\"Item1\":[{\"Id\":2,\"Title\":\"Support\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":14},{\"Id\":8,\"Title\":\"Helpdesk\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1},{\"Id\":7,\"Title\":\"Hostmaster\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1},{\"Id\":4,\"Title\":\"Salg\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1}],\"Item2\":[{\"Id\":8,\"FullName\":\"person 1\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":5},{\"Id\":3,\"FullName\":\"Person 2\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":4},{\"Id\":11,\"FullName\":\"Person 3\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":3},{\"Id\":14,\"FullName\":\"Person 4\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1},{\"Id\":12,\"FullName\":\"Person 5\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1},{\"Id\":7,\"FullName\":\"Person 7\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1},{\"Id\":4,\"FullName\":\"Person 8\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1}]}"
    var dashboard = [];
    dashboard.push(JSON.parse(elmJSON));
    //console.log(dashboard);
    dashboard.forEach(function(value){
        //console.log(value)
        for (var key in value) {
          if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            //console.log(value[key]);
            value[key].forEach(function(val){
              var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + val.Id + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.FullName + "</td>" +"<td>" + val.TotalUnresolvedItems + "</td>" + "</tr>"
              var tblRow2 = "<tr>" + "<td>" + val.Id + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.Title + "</td>" +"<td>" + val.TotalUnresolvedItems + "</td>" + "</tr>"
             
              $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
              $(tblRow2).appendTo("#userdata2 tbody");
             
            })
          }
        }
        
        
   });
   
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
    <table id= "userdata" border="2">
         <thead>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>TotalUnresolvedItems</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

       </tbody>
   </table>
        <table id= "userdata2" border="2">
     <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>FullName</th>
        <th>TotalUnresolvedItems</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `data.dashboard` is not in the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the data, you can do something like following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elmJSON = "{\"Item1\":[{\"Id\":2,\"Title\":\"Support\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":14},{\"Id\":8,\"Title\":\"Helpdesk\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1},{\"Id\":7,\"Title\":\"Hostmaster\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1},{\"Id\":4,\"Title\":\"Salg\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1}],\"Item2\":[{\"Id\":8,\"FullName\":\"André Lund\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":5},{\"Id\":3,\"FullName\":\"Arne Hundewadt\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":4},{\"Id\":11,\"FullName\":\"Erik Nymand\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":3},{\"Id\":14,\"FullName\":\"michael Povlsen\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1},{\"Id\":12,\"FullName\":\"Rene Nicolaj buch\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1},{\"Id\":7,\"FullName\":\"Bjørn Hansen\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1},{\"Id\":4,\"FullName\":\"Jakob Wensien-Jegsen\",\"TotalUnresolvedItems\":1}]}"
    var dashboard = [];
    dashboard.push(JSON.parse(elmJSON));
    dashboard.forEach(function(value, index){;
        for (var key in value) {
          if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if(key==='Item1'){
              value[key].forEach(function(val){
                var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + val.Id + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.Title + "</td>" +"<td>" + val.TotalUnresolvedItems + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
              })
            }
            if(key==='Item2'){
              value[key].forEach(function(val){
                var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + val.Id + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.FullName + "</td>" +"<td>" + val.TotalUnresolvedItems + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata2 tbody");
              })
            }
          }
        }
        
        
   });
   
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
    <strong>Item1:</strong>
    <table id= "userdata" border="2">
         <thead>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>TotalUnresolvedItems</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

       </tbody>
   </table>
   <strong>Item2:</strong>
   <table id= "userdata2" border="2">
         <thead>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>FullName</th>
            <th>TotalUnresolvedItems</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much looks great. Do you have any ide how can I replace undefined rows with the person name. Like item.Title --> item.FullName ?

Comment: All the data are coming from json. There is no Title property in the Item2. That's why it is undefined. Either you need separate table for Item2 or you need to restructure your json file.

Comment: Did you understand what I was saying?

Comment: I think I have understood what do you mean and I have edited my code and I made two different table It,s seems to be working but I do still get 7 undefined from first table in the end and 4 undefined from secon table from top?

Comment: Try the snippet now. I have updated the code to show data in two different tables. Let me know whether that solves your problem or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse it to JSON, it is currently a string representing a JSON object.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=UTF-8>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var dashboard = [];
   $.getJSON('ticket.json', function(data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
    var keys = Object.keys(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(keys[i])) {
            $.each(data[keys[i]], function (index, item) {
                var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + item.Id + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.Title + "</td>" +"<td>" + item.TotalUnresolvedItems + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
            });
        }
    }
     });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
    <table id= "userdata" border="2">
     <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>TotalUnresolvedItems</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. its solve my problem. But I am not able to accept you answer becouse I have less then 15 Reputation :)

Comment: Haha that's a bummer :\ 
Don't forget me when you will earn this reputation